# Creating method for division

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to write a method that takes two integers a and b and divides them. However I want the result to be a double. I've tried two ways:

**(1)**

```
public int divide(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
       System.out.println("Error, division by zero is undefined!");
    return 0;
    }  
    else {
       a = Double.parseDouble(a);
       b = Double.parseDouble(b);
       return a / b;
    }
}
```

**(2)** (*cast*)

```
public int divide(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
       System.out.println("Error, division by zero is undefined!");
    return 0;
    }  
    else {
       return (double) a / b;
    }
}
```

The first code generates the error message:

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
        a = Double.parseDouble(a);
                               ^
```

While the second generates the error message:

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Double
        return (Double) a / b;
                        ^
```

Can anyone explain why these codes don't work and show me how to write a functioning code?

Comment: In the second method's error message (as you posted it), `Double` is referring to a class. Use `double` (lowercase d) instead, which is a primitive type.

Comment: That second error does not match that second code snippet.

Comment: Also, you say you want to return a `double`, but both methods are returning `int`s. You don't think there might be an issue there?

Comment: Your code for (2) says you have `return (double) a / b;` (which should work), but your error message says you have `return (Double) a / b;` (which won't work).  Which is it?  Please be careful to make sure you replicate your code _exactly_ when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double.parseDouble() requires a string as input, so Double.parseDouble("4") works, but Double.parseDouble(4) is incorrect.
Try changing all parameters to doubles and the return type to a double to avoid doing type casting inside the code.  Also, if the user wanted to divide two decimal values he/she would not need to call another function to do so.

```
public double divide(double numerator, double denominator)
{
    if(denominator == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Error cannot divide by 0");
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return numerator / denominator;
    }
}
```

If you want the parameters to be integers, then you need to return a typecast.

```
public double divide(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    if(denominator == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Error cannot divide by 0");
        return 0;
    }
    return (double)numberator / denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public double divide(int a, int b)
 { 
   if (b == 0) 
   {
       System.out.println("Error, division by zero is undefined!"); 
       return 0; 
    } 
    else 
    {

         return ((double)a) / b;
     } 
   }
```

Your only problem was returning an int and cast to a Double object.

Answer (score 1):

You method returns an `int`, but `return (Double) a / b;` returns a double.
You should change it so that you either have

```
public double divide(int a, int b) {
```

as the first line (if you want to return a `double`) OR

```
return (int) a / b;
```

if you want to return an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want your result to be double, then you need to change the return type of your function double.
2. Use Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(a)) to get double value.
3. If you don't change the return type of you function then there will be loss of 
   precision in case if you get the response as decimal value. So do change the 
   return type of your function

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(a))` - is `(double) a` too mainstream?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `Double.parseDouble()` takes a String to return a double:

```
 public double divide(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
           System.out.println("Error, division by zero is undefined!");
        return 0;
        }  
        else {
           double c = Double.parseDouble(a + ".0");
           double d = Double.parseDouble(b + ".0");
           return c / d;
        }
    }
```

In the second methode you need to cast correctly:

```
public double divide(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
       System.out.println("Error, division by zero is undefined!");
    return 0;
    }  
    else {
       return ((double)a) / ((double)b);
    }
}
```